# Merge in eclipse or github - which is correct?

Tags: github, egit

New to github and from cvs background, I created branch from master branch work on it and everything looks good. Now have to merge my branch back to master branch.

I can do this in eclipse or in github.

What is the difference between doing merge in eclipse and github and which is the correct way ?

Comment: Both are valid ways to do a merge; there is also a third option, merging via the command line.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thank you. Is there industry standard on this or its just developer preference ?

Comment: If your organization tells you to do it a certain way, then do it that way.  I personally recommend starting with the Git bash and then moving to the UI based tools only once you really know how the basics work.